# Regex for white space and then line end

Tags: regex, textpad

I am struggling to find this - I need to strip all empty lines which might have white space before them

The alternative is messing about in Excel - I am using TextPad

Comment: I think you're bluffing about Excel.

Comment: Why?? Trim and then filter will do this quite easily - The suggestion below dont work in TextPad....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\s*$
```

If you've got perl-compatible regex.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [blog post on wordpress.com](http://frogsbrain.wordpress.com/2007/07/23/textpad-regular-expressions-replace-leading-whitespace-with-nbsp/), it's

```
^[[:space:]]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple reg ex for any empty line which may contain white space is:

```
^[ \t]*$
```

Answer (score 3):

In Textpad: First find blank line: F5, then ^\s*$

Next mark 'em: in the find dialog, click the "Mark All" button.  You see right-carets next to each blank line.

Then delete 'em: Select Edit->Delete ->Bookmarked Lines

Comment: After years of using Textpad never knew this existed ... was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove the line, this will not do:

```
^\s*$
```

You need to remove the line break after the empty line:

```
^\s*$[\n\r]*
```